# Bulk Conversion Of Kubuntu Master Video Folder Using FFmpeg?

Tags: ubuntu, video, ffmpeg, type-conversion

I have an old archive of videos (Around 400GB/1024 files) that are heavily structured due to the program that created them at the time.

There is a single folder called `master` that contains many other folders for specific events that were recorded. I was thinking of using `for i in *.vob; do ffmpeg -i "$i" "${i%.*}.mp4"; done` (From another SO user's answer on another question), but this is insufficient since the .vob files aren't all in the `master` folder are are instead in different folders in `master`.

Furthermore, the .vob titles are nonsense (And even worse overlapping! Video 1 (In Folder 1), Video 1 (In Folder 2) so they can't all be named the same thing in the same folder if I joined all of them.

My question is can I do a tree traversal of `master` using a script (I'm running KDE) that takes each `.vob` files and converts it using somthing similar to `for i in *.vob; do ffmpeg -i "$i" "${i%.*}.mp4"; done` in `master`, but with the name of the folder instead of the name of the file?

So, if we were in the `Assault On The Control Room` folder and converted `Video 1` and `Video 2`, could this output `Assault On The Control Room 1` and `Assault On The Control Room 2` and move the converted file to `/somefilepath/master2` that contains all the converted files?

The labels would obviously be set using ffmpeg and a for loop, but my scripting skills aren't up to this task yet.

**EDIT 0:** Output of `shopt -s globstar; for v1 in **/*.vob; do v2=$(awk -F'/' '{print "/somefilepath/master2/" $(NF-1) " - " $NF ".mp4"}' <<< "$v1"); ffmpeg -i "$v1" "$v2"; done`

> `sarah@ConvergentRefuge:/media/sarah/SENTINEL/Master$ shopt -s globstar; for v1 in **/*.vob; do v2=$(awk -F'/' '{print "/media/sarah/SENTINEL/Videos/NewMaster" $(NF-1) " - " $NF ".mp4"}' <<< "$v1"); ffmpeg -i "$v1" "$v2"; done
>   ffmpeg version N-91290-g6129b13 Copyright (c) 2000-2018 the FFmpeg developers
>     built with gcc 7 (Ubuntu 7.3.0-16ubuntu3)
>     configuration: --prefix=/home/sarah/ffmpeg_build --pkg-config-flags=--static --extra-cflags=-I/home/sarah/ffmpeg_build/include --extra-ldflags=-L/home/sarah/ffmpeg_build/lib --extra-libs='-lpthread -lm' --bindir=/home/sarah/bin --enable-gpl --enable-libass --enable-libfdk-aac --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopus --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-nonfree
>     libavutil      56. 18.102 / 56. 18.102
>     libavcodec     58. 20.102 / 58. 20.102
>     libavformat    58. 17.100 / 58. 17.100
>
>     libavdevice    58.  4.101 / 58.  4.101
>
>     libavfilter     7. 25.100 /  7. 25.100
>
>     libswscale      5.  2.100 /  5.  2.100
>
>     libswresample   3.  2.100 /  3.  2.100
>     libpostproc    55.  2.100 / 55.  2.100
>   **/*.vob: No such file or directory`

**EDIT 1**: View of Master Folder
[image: View of Master Folder]

Comment: @oguzismail Seems like it couldn't find the wildcard :). Maybe something wrong with the syntax?

Comment: nope, if you're using bash it should work

Comment: @oguzismail I'm using Konsole. I'm unfamiliar with `shopt -s globstar` as a command, but it appears to run. Maybe my system setup  is wrong somehow? I posted the output as an edit to the question. Maybe you can see something wrong with it?

Comment: see [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/117826/bash-globstar-matching) and read about `globstar`, i don't have access to my computer at this moment